# Selecting rows from one DataFrame depending on values from another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Take two data frames

```
print(df1)

   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  3
2  a  5
3  b  7
4  b  9
5  c  11
6  c  13
7  c  15

print(df2)

   C     D
a  apple 1
b  pear  1
c  apple 1
```

So the values in column `df1['A']` are the indexes of `df2`.

I want to select the rows in `df1` where the values in column `A` are `'apple'` in `df2['C']`. Resulting in:

```
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  3
2  a  5
5  c  11
6  c  13
7  c  15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made many edits due to comments and question edits,
Basically you first extract the indexes of df2 by filtering the dataframe by values in C, then filter the df2 by indexes with `isin`

```
indexes = df2[df2['C']=='apple'].index
df1[df1['A'].isin(indexes)]
>>>
   A  B
0  a  1
1  a  3
2  a  5
5  c  11
6  c  13
7  c  15
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to minimize memory allocation try to prevent saving information, (note. That i am not sure ot will solve your menory allocation issue because i didnt have full details of the situation and maybe even not suited enough to provide a solution):

```
df1[df1['A'].isin( df2[df2['C']=='apple'].index)]
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for my smaller data frames but but my `df1` has 600 rows and my `df2` has 700,000 rows and I get a memory error.

Comment: Thanks for your help but still memory error. I'll try structure the data frames differently.

Comment: Good luck! Was nice to help